# javascript show/hide table of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show/hide my table of content menu from genereted by AsciiDoctor. It is my HTML code:

```css
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li:active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="toc" class="toc2">
  <div id="toctitle">TEST TEST</div>
  <ul class="sectlevel1">
    <li><a href="#_test1">1. TEST1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test2">2. TEST2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test3">3. TEST3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test4">4. TEST4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test5">5. TEST5</a>
      <ul class="sectlevel2">
        <li><a href="#_test51">5.1. TEST51</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test6">6. TEST6</a>
      <ul class="sectlevel2">
        <li><a href="#_test61">6.1. TEST61</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#_test62">6.2. TEST62</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I click the element in table of content menu I want show children if I click second time I want hide this.

Comment: Do you need it on click? Hover would be easier: `ul li:hover ul { display: block; }`....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `jquery`

First of all, you need to trigger a `click` event handler for each list item. Secondly, you need to check if list item clicked has `ul` children, and if true need to show or hide elements.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
  var uls=$(this).parent('li').find('ul');
  if(uls.length>0){
    uls.is(":visible") ? uls.hide() : uls.show();
  }
});
```

```js
$('li a').click(function() {
  var uls = $(this).parent('li').find('ul');
  if (uls.length > 0) {
    uls.is(":visible") ? uls.hide() : uls.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="article toc2 toc-left">
  <div id="toc" class="toc2">
    <div id="toctitle">TEST TEST</div>
    <ul class="sectlevel1">
      <li><a href="#_test1">1. TEST1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#_test2">2. TEST2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#_test3">3. TEST3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#_test4">4. TEST4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#_test5">5. TEST5</a>
        <ul class="sectlevel2">
          <li><a href="#_test51">5.1. TEST51</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#_test6">6. TEST6</a>
        <ul class="sectlevel2">
          <li><a href="#_test61">6.1. TEST61</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#_test62">6.2. TEST62</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

One simply method is to use directly `toggle` method.

With this, you can toggle between the `hide()` and `show()` methods.

Something like this:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
  var uls=$(this).parent('li').find('ul');
  if(uls.length>0){
    uls.toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: `.toggle` handles your ternary operation automatically

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add an event listener. In that, check for first `ul`. You can use one of following

- $(this).parent().find('ul')
- $(this).next('ul')

To `hide/show`, you can use `$(..).toggle`

#### Sample

```js
$('li a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('ul:first').toggle()
})
```

```css
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li:active ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toc" class="toc2">
  <div id="toctitle">TEST TEST</div>
  <ul class="sectlevel1">
    <li><a href="#_test1">1. TEST1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test2">2. TEST2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test3">3. TEST3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test4">4. TEST4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test5">5. TEST5</a>
      <ul class="sectlevel2">
        <li><a href="#_test51">5.1. TEST51</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#_test6">6. TEST6</a>
      <ul class="sectlevel2">
        <li><a href="#_test61">6.1. TEST61</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#_test62">6.2. TEST62</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```